# Octave not able to evaluate script due to failure in loading scalar constant

Tags: java, octave

I have a project where I need to make several computations using Octave. I communciate with Octave using the javaoctave bridge. Below is simplified example code to show what I am doing.

```
// One of the fields of my class that evaluates equations. This class is provided by teh bridge.
private OctaveEngine scriptEngine;
// The script contains the equation, e.g.: Ampere = PowerConsumption (Lights, Dryer, Dishwasher, Laptop, Smartphone);
private String script;

public synchronized void evaluate() {
    // Variable is a class implementing Cloneable and harbouring a unit as well as its unit and a few utility functions.
    LinkedHashSet<Variable> dependentVariables;
    String evaluationErrors;

    Preconditions.checkState(scriptEngine != null);

    try {
        engineErrors.reset();
        scriptEngine.setErrorWriter(engineErrors);
        initParameters();
        scriptEngine.eval(this.script);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while evaluating script " + this.script, exception); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    // The mapping stores the variables and the interface objects changing or reading their values.
    dependentVariables = mapping.getDependentVariables();
    for (Variable variable : dependentVariables) {
        try {
            OctaveDouble result = scriptEngine.get(OctaveDouble.class, variable.getName());
            variable.setValue(result.get(1));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while retrieving variable " + variable.getName(), exception); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }

    evaluationErrors = engineErrors.toString();

    if (evaluationErrors.length() > 0) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Error while evaluating equation :" + evaluationErrors); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}

private void initParameters() {
    for (Variable variable : lockedMapping.getIndependentVariables()) {
        Double numericValue = Double.valueOf(variable.getValue().toString());

        if (isNegative(numericValue)) {
            numericValue *= -1d;
        }
        scriptEngine.put(variable.getName(), Octave.scalar(numericValue));
    }
}

private static boolean isNegative(double _double) {
    return Double.doubleToRawLongBits(_double) < 0;
}
```

What I was getting as error message was that:

```
WARNING: Error while evaluating equation :error: load: failed to load scalar constant
error: load: trouble reading ascii file '-'
error: load: reading file -
```

Googling a bit I [found](https://kenai.com/projects/help/forums/general/topics/2061-problems-with-PUT-method-of-octaveengine) that negative values (or large inputs) can cause this problem. However, it was deemed to be solved. I don't have large inputs and I tried to make sure my values are positive (which all were even by testing using a syso!

I did a more in-depth search for the root cause and stumbled upon it. It seems that in the [`OcaveExec`](https://github.com/prateek/javaoctave/blob/master/src/main/java/dk/ange/octave/exec/OctaveExec.java) class, line 157 in the `getFromFuture` method where it calles `future.get()`, an `ExecutionException` is thrown. Below is the immediate stacktrace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: IOException during close
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.getFromFuture(OctaveExec.java:157)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.eval(OctaveExec.java:142)
    at dk.ange.octave.io.OctaveIO.set(OctaveIO.java:56)
    at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngine.put(OctaveEngine.java:141)
    at [redacted].OctaveEquation.initParameters(OctaveEquation.java:109)
    at [redacted].OctaveEquation.evaluate(OctaveEquation.java:72)
    at [redacted].LinearEquationSystem.inputChanged(LinearEquationSystem.java:105)
    at [redacted].variable.NumericalVariable.setValue(NumericalVariable.java:127)
    at [redacted].widget.ValueWidget.actionDrop(ValueWidget.java:88)
    at [redacted].TangibleObjectManager.dropObject(TangibleObjectManager.java:207)
    at [redacted].adapter.TuioAdapter.addTangibleObject(TuioAdapter.java:318)
    at [redacted].adapter.TuioAdapter.addTuioObject(TuioAdapter.java:295)
    at TUIO.TuioClient.acceptMessage(TuioClient.java:339)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchMessage(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:73)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchPacket(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:49)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchBundle(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchPacket(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:40)
    at com.illposed.osc.OSCPortIn.run(OSCPortIn.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: IOException during close
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:65)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe to octave-process broken
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExecuteReader.read(OctaveExecuteReader.java:68)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExecuteReader.close(OctaveExecuteReader.java:96)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:61)
    ... 5 more
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: IOException during close
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.getFromFuture(OctaveExec.java:157)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExec.eval(OctaveExec.java:142)
    at dk.ange.octave.io.OctaveIO.set(OctaveIO.java:56)
    at dk.ange.octave.OctaveEngine.put(OctaveEngine.java:141)
    at [redacted].OctaveEquation.initParameters(OctaveEquation.java:109)
    at [redacted].OctaveEquation.evaluate(OctaveEquation.java:72)
    at [redacted].LinearEquationSystem.inputChanged(LinearEquationSystem.java:105)
    at [redacted].variable.NumericalVariable.setValue(NumericalVariable.java:127)
    at [redacted].widget.ValueWidget.actionDrop(ValueWidget.java:88)
    at [redacted].TangibleObjectManager.dropObject(TangibleObjectManager.java:207)
    at [redacted].adapter.TuioAdapter.addTangibleObject(TuioAdapter.java:318)
    at [redacted].adapter.TuioAdapter.addTuioObject(TuioAdapter.java:295)
    at TUIO.TuioClient.acceptMessage(TuioClient.java:339)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchMessage(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:73)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchPacket(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:49)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchBundle(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.illposed.osc.utility.OSCPacketDispatcher.dispatchPacket(OSCPacketDispatcher.java:40)
    at com.illposed.osc.OSCPortIn.run(OSCPortIn.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: dk.ange.octave.exception.OctaveIOException: IOException during close
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:65)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe to octave-process broken
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExecuteReader.read(OctaveExecuteReader.java:68)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveExecuteReader.close(OctaveExecuteReader.java:96)
    at dk.ange.octave.exec.OctaveReaderCallable.call(OctaveReaderCallable.java:61)
    ... 5 more
```

I am working on a Windows 7 machine, have the path to the Octave bin on my classpath and not sure what I am doing wrong. I assume something goes wrong during IO but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

To be sure all my inputs are known, below are my *.m filed holding both scripts. All my inputs are positive and range from 0 to 2200 (as doubles).

```
function Load = CircuitLoad(Breaker, Lights, Dryer, Dishwasher, Laptop, Smartphone)
Load = Breaker / ((Lights + Dryer + Dishwasher + Laptop + Smartphone) / 230);
```

And the second one:

```
function Ampere = PowerConsumption(Lights, Dryer, Dishwasher, Laptop, Smartphone)
Ampere = (Lights + Dryer + Dishwasher + Laptop + Smartphone) / 230;
```